# What is Kolmogorov strong law of large numbers?

Tags: statistics

I am doing a statistical physics course and just started information theory. In one exercise they use a convergence and a notation I do not understand and claim to use Kolmogorov's strong law. The exercise is as follows:

**[Beginning]**

Consider $N$ independent random variables $x_{i} .$ What does $r\left(\left\{x_{i}\right\}\right)=1 / N \log _{2} [1 / P_{N}\left(\left\{x_{i}\right\}\right)]$ converge to as $N \rightarrow$ $\infty ?$ Deduce what is the typical probability of a sequence $P_{N}\left(\left\{x_{i}\right\}\right)$

**Solution:** We have
$$
\begin{aligned}
r\left(\left\{x_{i}\right\}\right) &=\frac{1}{N} \log _{2} \frac{1}{P_{N}\left(\left\{x_{i}\right\}\right)} \\
&=-\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i} \log _{2} P\left(\left\{x_{i}\right\}\right) \\
& \rightarrow-\left\langle\log _{2} P\left(x_{i}\right)\right\rangle_{i}=H_{\bar{x}}
\end{aligned}
$$
where $H_{\bar{x}}=\frac{1}{N} H_{\{x\}} .$ We used the Kolmogorov strong law of large numbers since the random variables are independent, but not identical.

**[End]**

What does $-\left\langle\log _{2} P\left(x_{i}\right)\right\rangle_{i}$ mean and how does one determine this convergence with Kolmogorov's strong law ? Sorry if this is obvious I have not done statistics in forever.

Thanks in advance,

(Merry Christmas!)

Comment: What's the textbook that you're using?

Comment: Well its complicated, the course does not really have official notes ...

Comment: Well, I think is important the notation in your post. If you want to learn the Strong Law of Large Number I recommend you to read here: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/06/18/the-strong-law-of-large-numbers/